# Is i holomorphic over the whole complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

That is, is i entire? I know that it's derivative with respect to z bar is 0, so I would think that the answer is yes, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is analytic everywhere. In fact, the only bounded entire functions are constant functions.

Comment: Oh ok, so it's as I thought. I was wondering that given f entire, is f(z)(fzbar) = |f(z)|^2? I was given the counter example of i.

Comment: Clearly that example shows that $f(z) f(\bar{z}) \neq |f(z)|^2$ in general or even for entire functions. But it doesn't seem to me that that not holding would have any impact on a function not having a derivative.

Comment: For some reason I was convinced that that equation was true so much so that I had to question whether or not i was a valid counterexample.

Comment: I realized why I was confused, I confused f(z)f(z¯) with f(z)conj(f(z))!